# Creating requriements.txt in conda doesn't show versions

Tags: python, pip, conda, environment, requirements.txt

I've been working inside a conda environment (python==3.6). I've been trying to make a requirements.txt using

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

The file shows the following:

`pandas @ file:///C:/ci/pandas_1602088210462/work`

and

`Pillow @ file:///C:/ci/pillow_1609842634117/work`

I was expecting to see:
`pandas==1.1.3`

Does anyone has a resolution.

Comment: `pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conda list --export > requirements.txt` to export a conda-compliant list of package you can then import using:
`conda install --file requirements.txt`

Or, as others said, you can also use: `pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Conda does not export valid PyPI package specifications, which seems to be want OP wants. That is, even though this format is syntactically similar to the `pip freeze` output, it will yield a list of Conda packages not PyPI ones and therefore will not necessarily be compatible with using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.